# How to set session timeout for OAuth2 response in hybris

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, session-timeout, spartacus-storefront

The requirement is to set timeout for a cart in **spartacus** storefront. I am trying to achieve by setting the value as ***oauth2.refreshTokenValiditySeconds=1000*** in local.properties but it is not working. Is there any way to achieve this.

Comment: What do you mean by setting timout for cart?
You might also want to look at accessToken session length if you want to have short session for users.

Comment: are you talking about user session?

Comment: @RaushanKumar it is to invalidate the API response. For example anonymous user loaded the cart by adding an item and after 30(session timeout) minutes if he tried to refresh the page the cart should be empty because of session timeout.